# For Python 3.4: How do I write an import module statement that works from any scope?

Tags: python, import, package, python-3.4

Summary:

The same import statement that works when `__name__ == "__main__"` stops working when imported from another module outside the immediate package. If I fix it so that it works when imported, it stops working when `__name__ == "__main__"`. Is there a win-win solution for these conflicting scopes?

In more detail:

Say I have the following system layout.

```
package/
    __init__.py
    outer_module.py
    subpackage/
        __init__.py
        inner_module_1.py
        inner_module_2.py
```

And say that all modules are empty except for the following two.

```
# inner_module_1
import inner_module_2
```

&

```
# outer_module
import subpackage.inner_module_1
import subpackage.inner_module_2
```

If I run `inner_module_1`, there is no error.

If I run `outer_module`, I get the following ImportError from `inner_module_1`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\package\outer_module.py", line 1, in <module>
import subpackage.inner_module_1
File "C:\package\subpackage\inner_module_1.py", line 1, in <module>
import inner_module_2
ImportError: No module named 'inner_module_2'
```

I can prevent that error by adding the package name to the import statement in `inner_module_1` as follows.

```
# inner_module_1
import subpackage.inner_module_2
```

Although this change allows `outer_module` to run without an error, now running `inner_module_1`, which had before run without error, raises the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\package\subpackage\inner_module_1.py", line 1, in <module>
import subpackage.inner_module_2
ImportError: No module named 'subpackage'
```

So here are my questions.

Is the import statement in `inner_module_1` interpreted differently when accessed by `outer_module` than when run in `inner_module_1`, and if so, how so?

Can I write an import statement in `inner_module_1` that works both when `inner_module_1` is run and also when `outer_module` is run, and if so, what is that statement?

Thanks,

Victor

Comment: Simply don't try to run your modules as executables, instead run them with `python -msubpackage.inner_module_1`. Also you can use `from . import inner_module_2`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I may be forced to not run individual modules by a lack of alternatives, but if so, I would want to know why. What is the inherent impossibility/impracticality of this. I tried to run `inner_module_1` with a relative import and received the following error. SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import.

Comment: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

Comment: is it not package.subpackage.inner_module_1 ? As per your module design?

Comment: @PsyKzz, if I write `import package.subpackage.inner_module_1` in `outer_module`, I receive the following error when I run `outer_module`. `ImportError: No module named 'package'`